# Getting all decimals from interger being Squarooted

Tags: ios, objective-c

The solution of the square root of 11 in a normal calculator is roughly

3.31662479036

I am trying round to 3.32

So my problem I am having in iOS is;

In my `viewDidLoad`

```
int Mynumber = sqrt(11);
NSLog(@"%d", Mynumber);
```

I keep getting 3 when I should to get the first three integers. 
Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is for integers, not decimals. Use `float` and `%f`.

```
float myNumber = sqrtf(11);
NSLog(@"%.2f", myNumber);
```

Comment: @techman9 Also note how rmaddy changed your variable name. Camel case with a lower case first letter follows naming conventions. Avoid naming variables like MyCoolVariable (that's how you name classes) and use myCoolVariable.

Answer (score 1):

```
float theFloat = sqrt(11);
NSLog(@"%.2f", theFloat);
// also u can use integer round figur like this...
int rounded = lroundf(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",rounded);
int roundedUp = ceil(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedUp);
int roundedDown = floor(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedDown);
```